# About Interpolation Method using GIS10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, interpolation, hydrology

I have attached my stream network where the green dots shows the location with discharge gage now I want to create a raster all along the stream network to have a discharge data all along the river. Which Interpolation will be better. I have tried with IDW method but it's not working well. Please provide me some suggestion.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this as a network [flow](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Flow_direction_in_a_geometric_network) problem or even a weighted stream network such as [Strahler](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Stream%20Order) and then just convert the values to raster as opposed to interpolate as interpolation in this scenario would weight downstream and upstream equally if they are equally far apart (assuming equal magnitude).

Comment: The network idea is a good start because 2D interpolation is going to mix together flows from different non-communicating branches of the stream and therefore would be difficult to defend. But exactly how does interpolation happen during the conversion to raster format?

Comment: "as opposed to interpolate"

Comment: Your English construction is difficult to parse and the reference to "convert .. to raster" is ambiguous because there are many different ways to make such a conversion. Your reply seems to  say that the O.P. should *not* attempt to interpolate the data at all, but that doesn't answer the question. Exactly how does your answer accomplish what the O.P. is looking for?